# codeigniter instance of model class

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, instance

I'm developing a site with codeigniter. Now, normally when you use a class in codeigniter, you basically use it as if it were a static class. For example, if I head a model called 'user', I would first load it using

```
$this->load->model('user');
```

and than, I could invoke methods on that user class like

```
$this->user->make_sandwitch('cheese');
```

in the application that I'm building, I would like to have one UserManagement class, which uses a class called 'user'.

so that, for example I could

```
$this->usermanager->by_id(3);
```

and this would return an **instance** of the user model where the id is 3.
What's the best way to do that?

Comment: The best way is to use an ORM. Doctrine is popular one, and there are some tutorials on integration it with CodeIgniter

Comment: @bassneck thx for your suggestion. I'm probaly not going to use that in my current project, but I'll definitely look into doctrine, it looks awesome at first glance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The model classes in CI are not quite the same thing as model classes in other syntax's. In most cases, models will actually be some form of plain object with a database layer which interacts with it. With CI, on the other hand, `Model` represents the database layer interface which returns generic objects (they're kinda like arrays in some ways). I know, I feel lied to too.

So, if you want to make your Model return something which is not a `stdClass`, you need to wrap the database call.

So, here's what I would do:

Create a user_model_helper which has your model class:

```
class User_model {
    private $id;

    public function __construct( stdClass $val )
    {
        $this->id = $val->id; 
        /* ... */
        /*
          The stdClass provided by CI will have one property per db column.
          So, if you have the columns id, first_name, last_name the value the 
          db will return will have a first_name, last_name, and id properties.
          Here is where you would do something with those.
        */
    }
}
```

In usermanager.php:

```
class Usermanager extends CI_Model {
     public function __construct()
     {
          /* whatever you had before; */
          $CI =& get_instance(); // use get_instance, it is less prone to failure
                                 // in this context.
          $CI->load->helper("user_model_helper");
     }

     public function by_id( $id )
     {
           $q = $this->db->from('users')->where('id', $id)->limit(1)->get();
           return new User_model( $q->result() );
     }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the User_model manually. You can pass the model class name in as a parameter of result() and it will return a new instance filled with the data from the DB. `$q->result('User_model')`

Answer (score 0):

Use abstract factory pattern or even Data access object pattern which does the job that you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User extend CI_Model 
{
    function by_id($id) {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('users')->where('id', $id)->limit(1);
        // Your additional code goes here
        // ...
        return $user_data;
    }
}


class Home extend CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('user');
        $data = $this->user->by_id($id);
    }
}
```